# How to even dents and scrape marks over entire wall

Tags: drywall, painting, repainting, spackling-paste

Our hallway is painted brilliant white eggshell but has quite visible dent and scrape marks under the paint. What is the best way to even out the wall?

We will eventually cover a lot of the wall with artwork so we're thinking to spackle the worst looking areas (rather than the entire wall) and then paint over those areas with the correct existing eggshell colour but having never used spackle before I'm concerned this might make some parts of the wall look entirely different.

Images for reference (ignore the iPhone white balance making the colours a bit strange!):
[image]

[image]

Comment: What ever you end up doing, use the brightest, highest wattage work light you can find to expose every defect.  When it looks good under bright lights, it will look great under normal lights.

Comment: The second picture is simply bad mudding. A very bad job of applying drywall compound, nothing more.

Comment: TBH, most of that just looks like a bad mud job.

Answer (score 1):

I usually lightly sand and use standard Sheetrock mud, after it is dry I sand again if I think this looks good I then use a can of spray texture and blend some new texture with the old, after the spray texture is dry and a fresh coat of paint when we’ll done you really won’t see the repair. Never tape off an area when using spray texture that makes lines that stand out after painting (one of the best DIY repairs I have seen was spoiled because they taped off the area instead of blending.

Answer (score 1):

There are many types of patch material to use, but as you mentioned most repairs are done with spackle or joint compound. It's easy to apply, dries hard and is inexpensive.

I't easier to apply it if you load a tray, but can be used directly from the container. Use a 4 inch flexible putty knife for all small dents and damaged areas.

Apply the material on the putty knife at a 30-45 degree angle making as many passes so that the dent is filled. Try to over fill the repair so the spackle is slightly above the finished surface. Doing this will allow you to only make one application of the spackle rather then another as it will shrink when dried.

You can next sand the patches after letting it dry 24 hrs. use 100-120 grit sand paper attached to a sanding block. Sand in a circular motion  checking by running your hand over the patch intermittently. You shouldn't feel a bump over the repair.

Vacuum the sanded dust from the wall with a vacuum brush attachment. It wouldn't hurt to damp sponge the entire wall.

When painting walls that have spackled areas you will need to spot prime the patches. This will allow a uniform look when the finish coat is applied. Otherwise the patched areas would show through as a duller paint shade. After primer dries apply finish coat to entire wall.

Comment: Filling deep pockets in 1 shot will leave divots as the mud drys and the mud may crack, setting compound or hot mud won’t crack but it drys quickly. The problem with hot mud is it is hard to sand. Priming without texturing is going to show worse than the existing surface.